# Java/Swing: Update data on stateChange

Tags: java, swing

I have a list of `Map.Entry<String,Integer>`s that I am looping through, and for each one, making a `JLabel`/`JSpinner` representing that particular entry.

How can I make it so that when the `ChangeListener` fires on the `JSpinner`, it updates that entry to reflect the new value?

My code looks like

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : graph.getData()) {
    SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(
      entry.getValue(),(Integer)0,(Integer)100,(Integer)5);
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);

    JLabel label = new JLabel(entry.getKey());

    spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            entry.setValue((Integer)((JSpinner)e.getSource()).getValue());
        }
    });

    // more stuff
}
```

However, this does not work, because entry either needs to be final or object-level, and it is neither.

Is there an easier way, like C#'s `dataSource` that directly binds the object to the spinner? Or how can I make this work?

Comment: Can't you make the entry final? like for(final Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry:graph.getData())....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options if you want to stick with individual `JLabel` and `JSpinner`. Use @trashgod's answer if the map could get large.

1. WRONG Per @Suresh Kumar's comment: `final Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry`
2. WRONG Add `spinner.putClientProperty("MyEntryKey", entry)`, then in your ChangeListener get the entry with `spinner.getClientProperty`.
3. Add `spinner.putClientProperty("MyEntryKey", entry.getKey())`, then in your ChangeListener `graph.put(spinner.getClientProperty(), ...)`.
4. From @Michael's answer (not sure if this is ethical): Add `final String key = entry.getKey()`, then in your ChangeListener `graph.put(key, ...)`.
5. Let your enclosing class implement `ChangeListener` to avoid one `ChangeListener` per `JSpinner`:

   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
       JSpinner spinner = (JSpinner)e.getSource();
       graph.put((String)spinner.getClientProperty("MyEntryKey"), (Integer)spinner.getValue());
   }

BTW `graph.getData()` looks a bit odd. If `graph` implements `Map`, you should use `graph.entrySet()`.

Comment: `Map.Entry` refs are invalid after the iterator is complete, so only (original) solution #3 will work reliably.

Comment: Oops, sorry for such n00b error. I guess I should really get `-2+1=-1` votes.

Comment: Well, no graph isn't a `Map`, but it does contain one. It's also not a Graph like with edges and vertices. It is a VERY simple way of representing data to be displayed in a pie/bar/line/etc graph.

Answer (score 1):

Particularly if the number of `Map` entries is large, consider using a [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), with your `Map` as the core of the data model and a custom render/editor extending `JSpinner`. There's a related example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Answer (score 1):

@Suresh is right about using `final` in the for loop, but since `Map.Entry` values aren't viable outside of the iterator, this would lead to trouble.  Another possibility for this one-way binding would be

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : graph.getData()) {
    ...
    final String key = entry.getKey();

    spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            graph.put(key, (Integer)((JSpinner)e.getSource()).getValue());
        }
    });
```

For a more complete data binding, you may want a more complex object to bind against.  See the [jgoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) binding API's `ValueModel` and `SpinnerAdapterFactory`, for example.